# How to set a duration for toggleClass in navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[**FIXED**] Check my comment

I am trying to make a header responsive for mobile view. After I was done i wanted to set a duration for the menu when clicked on the menubar. But after trying multiple times I still cant figure out why the `transisiton` doesn't work. I don't know if it is because of my bad css or something else. I also tried the inbuilt duration `toggleClass` offers but it didnt worked. I hope someone can help me figure this out.

```js
/*********************** TOGGLE MENU BAR ***********************/

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu_bar').on('click', function() {
        $('#menu_item').toggleClass('open', 2000); //didnt worked
    })
})
```

```css
****************************** GENERAL  ******************************/

 :root {
    --background: #1A1A1A;
    --second-background: #212121;
    --main-green: #38b000;
    --highlight-color: #a2a012;
    --font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    --text-color: #ffffff;
    --right: margin-right: 422px;
    --left: margin-left: 422px;
    --hover-color: #dd7700;
}

 ::selection {
    color: var(--text-color);
    background-color: #696969;
}

*:hover {
    transition: all 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms;
    -o-transition: all 300ms;
}

a {
    color: var(--text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.right {
    margin-right: 11%;
}

.left {
    margin-left: 11%;
}


/****************************** GENERAL BODY ******************************/

html,
body {
    background-color: var(--background);
    color: var(--text-color);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: var(--font-family);
}


/****************************** HEADER ******************************/

header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: var(--second-background);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #363636;
}

header img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px
}

.logo {
    padding: 5px 0 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navbar ul {
    display: flex;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
}

#menu_bar {
    float: right;
    margin: 6px 5px 0 0;
    display: none;
}

#menu_bar:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--hover-color);
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
    header img {
        width: 160px;
    }
    #menu_bar {
        display: inline;
    }
    #navbar {
        display: inline;
    }
    #navbar ul {
        height: 0;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: none;
    }
    #navbar ul.open {
        height: auto;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #363636;
    }
    #navbar ul {
        background: var(--second-background);
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    }
    #navbar li {
        padding: 0.7rem 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Verna</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/img/icon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/fa/css/brands.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/fa/css/solid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/responsive.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!---------------------------- HEADER ---------------------------->
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="logo">
            <div id="menu_bar">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="46" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="fill: #000000;">
                    <path d="M4 6h16v2H4zm0 5h16v2H4zm0 5h16v2H4z"></path>
                </svg>
            </div>

            <ul id="menu_item">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


        </nav>

    </header>

    <!---------------------------- HEADER ---------------------------->
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src=""></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
    <script src="/assets/script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: jQuery's toggleClass doesn't have a duration parameter. See https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: you haven't explained clearly, try **setTimeout()**

Comment: @EliasSoares It does have but we need to include the jquery Ui library in order to use it

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa Thank you for the comment but now it is working. It was because i forgot to include a library from jQuery.

Comment: I'm glad you're fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you haven't included the jquery UI Library!

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-0vBSIAi/8FxkNOSKyPEfdGQzFDak1dlqFKBYqBp1yC4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It is necessary in order to use the duration in toggleClass.

Answer (score 0):

Use `slideToggle` for `display: none` menu instead off setting class as height can not be animated with CSS (actually it can be animated with max-height value, but there are some downsides for this approach)

```js
/*********************** TOGGLE MENU BAR ***********************/

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu_bar').on('click', function() {
        $('#menu_item').slideToggle(200);
    })
})
```

```css
****************************** GENERAL  ******************************/

 :root {
    --background: #1A1A1A;
    --second-background: #212121;
    --main-green: #38b000;
    --highlight-color: #a2a012;
    --font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    --text-color: #ffffff;
    --right: margin-right: 422px;
    --left: margin-left: 422px;
    --hover-color: #dd7700;
}

 ::selection {
    color: var(--text-color);
    background-color: #696969;
}

*:hover {
    transition: all 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms;
    -o-transition: all 300ms;
}

a {
    color: var(--text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.right {
    margin-right: 11%;
}

.left {
    margin-left: 11%;
}


/****************************** GENERAL BODY ******************************/

html,
body {
    background-color: var(--background);
    color: var(--text-color);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: var(--font-family);
}


/****************************** HEADER ******************************/

header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: var(--second-background);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #363636;
}

header img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px
}

.logo {
    padding: 5px 0 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navbar ul {
    display: flex;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
}

#menu_bar {
    float: right;
    margin: 6px 5px 0 0;
    display: none;
}

#menu_bar:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--hover-color);
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
    header img {
        width: 160px;
    }
    #menu_bar {
        display: inline;
    }
    #navbar {
        display: inline;
    }
    #navbar ul {
        display: none;
    }
    #navbar ul.open {
        height: auto;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #363636;
    }
    #navbar ul {
        background: var(--second-background);
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    }
    #navbar li {
        padding: 0.7rem 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Verna</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/img/icon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/fa/css/brands.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/fa/css/solid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/responsive.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!---------------------------- HEADER ---------------------------->
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="logo">
            <div id="menu_bar">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="46" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="fill: #000000;">
                    <path d="M4 6h16v2H4zm0 5h16v2H4zm0 5h16v2H4z"></path>
                </svg>
            </div>

            <ul id="menu_item">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


        </nav>

    </header>

    <!---------------------------- HEADER ---------------------------->
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src=""></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
    <script src="/assets/script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>

</html>
```